# How to use autograph and tf.device with tf.function wrapped class method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

In the following code, it is absolutely imperative for me to execute the complete function in GPU without a single jump back to CPU. This is because I have 4 CPU cores but I have 1200 cuda cores. Theoretically, it is possible because the tensorflow feed_forwards, if statements and and the variable assigns can be done on GPU (I have NVIDIA GTX 1060).

The problem I'm facing is tensorflow2.0 does this automatic assignment to GPU and CPU in the backend and doesn't mention which of it's ops are GPU compatible. When I run the following function with device as GPU, I get

```
parallel_func could not be transformed and will be staged without change.
```

and it runs sequentially on GPU.

My question is where to use tf.device? What part of code will be converted by autograph to GPU code and what will remain on CPU? How can I convert that too to GPU?

```
@tf.function
def parallel_func(self):
    for i in tf.range(114):                     #want this parallel on GPU
        for count in range(320):                #want this sequential on GPU

            retrivedValue = self.data[i][count]

            if self.var[i]==1:
                self.value[i] = retrievedValue     # assigns, if else
            elif self.var[i]==-1:                  # some links to class data through
                self.value[i] = -retrivedValue     # self.data, self.a and self.b

            state = tf.reshape(tf.Variable([self.a[i], self.b[i][count]]), [-1,2])

            if self.workerSwitch == False:
                action = tf.math.argmax(self.feed_forward(i, count, state))
            else:
                action = tf.math.argmax(self.worker_feed_forward(i, count, state))

            if (action==1 or action==-1):
                self.actionCount +=1
```

Comment: I wonder if some of the code in this discussion is the answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615954/understanding-device-allocation-parallelismtf-while-loop-and-tf-function-in-t

Answer (score 0):

Side note: the message `parallel_func could not be transformed and will be staged without change` is output by autograph, and since it contains data-dependent control flow, it's likely that the function can't run at all. It would be worth filing an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) with steps to reproduce and more detailed log messages.

Comment: Alex gives a lecture on tf.function. Each part of that lecture is very important to make the above code run. This should've run but autograph has a long way to go. I converted the above code to all being tensors ops and minimal python code like if, elif, while, continue and so on.